# WinRT ListView Binding to Items.Count

Tags: listview, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm incrementally loading a list view, this works fine and the data is shown in the list view.

I want to show the number of items currently in the list.

To test I have a button which display this count correctly.

However, if I try to bind to this count property it just shows 0.

Here the code I use to bind a text block to the list views items count.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Items.Count, ElementName=ListTwitterUserTweets, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

This code shows the figure though?

```
App.ShowMessageBox(ListTwitterUserTweets.Items.Count.ToString(), "Items Count");
```

Is the Items.Count not bindable or not a notifyable property.

I've seen examples of this for WPF, is it a WinRT problem?

Comment: In **WPF** `ItemCollection` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` but not in **WinRT** so this is probably the issue. So you'd better bind to an `ObservableCollection` and push your data into it, you should be able to bind to its `Count` property directly.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought!

Answer (score 1):

Instead, try this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Users.Count}" />
```

So, basically, try not to use Element binding for this simple task.

Best of luck.